# .htaccess for clean URL not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am working with PHP and htacess for the first time.  I am passing a variables in a query string to a URL and want this URL to look clean.  Please help.
.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^id-([0-9]+)/([0-9A-Za-z]+).html  /detail.php?id=$1&display=$2
```

PHP code passing from one file to detail page URL is:

```
<a href='/detail.php?id={$info[id]}&display=$title1'>
```

Please help.

Comment: What exactly is not working, and what exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Could you please add an example of a URL that would resemble the left-hand side of your RewriteRule directive?

Answer (score 2):

You need to print out the new URL in order to get it rewritten by mod_rewrite. Because mod_rewrite can only rewrite URLs that are requested. So try this:

```
<a href='/id-{$info[id]}-$title1.html'>
```

Comment: how about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13557696/url-re-writing-not-working-properly#comment18573058_13557696