# Apache URL Re-writing not functioning properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to use apache-rewrite rule to convert the below URL:

> `http://localhost/foo/bar/news.php?id=24`

Into this format:

> `http://localhost/foo/bar/news/foo-bar`

The number `24` is an `id` of a random row from a MySQL table, which also contains `title` and `content` fields.

```
MariaDB [blog]> select * from articles;
+----+---------+----------+ 
| id | title   | content  |
+----+---------+----------+ 
|  1 | foo-bar | bla bla  | 
+----+---------+----------+ 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have the following rule inside my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
^news/([A_Za_z0_9_]+)$ DIRECTORY/AID/news.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I also have a php code that generates a link like this:

```
$link = "<a href='news.php?id={$row['id']}'></a>";
echo $link;
```

However, I can't get the rewrite rule to change the path as the desired end result.

Comment: What happens when you visit /this_is_news ?

Comment: @alexLunix I tried it again actually, and it does not display the news

Comment: By "does not display the news" do you mean that it's blank, or is it still a 404?

Comment: It is blank, it does not display the news

Comment: It gave me blank when I removed the slash in `/news.php?news=$1` it gives me 404 when I add that slash

Comment: Check your apache access log and see what it's rewriting it to, because it's blank that means it's getting to the news.php file, but something isn't parsing correctly. Check for PHP errors as well in your logs.

Comment: @AlexLunix how do I check Apache logs? I am using XAMPP and I don't know where to find it. It could be also from the PHP script, as I made it myself and I am new. But, I am not getting any errors. All is working fine in PHP

Comment: Is the root of your application the root of the webserver ? any subfolder ? Try add "RewriteBase /" in 2nd line maybe ?

Comment: On the xampp control panel click explore and then open the apache folder, then the logs folder then look for a php error log.

Comment: @y_nk No, actually I am using many directories in my root so, I created a folder called `AID` for this website. so, my URL is `http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/` so this web page is found in `AID/` then `index.php` I tried the RewriteBase/ and it gave me a 404 page

Comment: Point the RewriteBase to the root folder of your webapp. So it would be something like RewriteBase /DIRECTORY/AID

Comment: it is inside the `AID/` together with the three files

Comment: I did that, and I can't even see the whole site which was in here `http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/` it just gave me 404

Comment: mhm, i forgot to say to add a slash at the end : RewriteBase /DIRECTORY/AID/ ?

Comment: I did that, the site isn't gone but the news is not displaying. and you can type anything after `http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/`and it does not matter, no 404 no result

Comment: What's the response code ? HTTP 200 ? You can see that in Firebug, Network tab (just in case)

Comment: (Said apart, you should add "Options +FollowSymLinks" in first line)

Comment: I don't know the response code or even what it means. I did applied (at the first line) your second suggestion still no result.

Comment: Update the question with what you have now.

Comment: @AlexLunix I have updated it, is should be fairly simple to understand the structure of the site.

Comment: Alex and @y_nk, I am rewarding you +1 for keeping up with my headaches. Thanks

Comment: Place `RewriteBase /DIRECTORY/AID/` after 
`RewriteEngine On`

Comment: Did it. No 404, and No result.. just a page without news.

Comment: This question is more thoroughly explained now, with +100 bounty.

Comment: I have added [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13737552/964616). Hope it helps.

Comment: @Simon_eQ - please pay attention more carefully in the Low Quality queue; [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3216086#./3216086?&_suid=1382724666930046612549906247086) is *not* okay, because it is a question in itself.  It should have been deleted.  Furthermore, [link-only answers](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/3215943#./3215943?&_suid=1382721628641035433087126675366) are not allowed, and this should have been deleted as well.  If you are in doubt, do not vote.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Ok, thanks. Made a silly mistake. I thought the link-only answer was probably legit..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you would need to change the href in the html, to give the new url format

```
function news_preview() {
$query = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5  ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{   
  echo "<a href=\"/news/$row[id]\">  ". substr($row['title'], 0,26)."...</a><br/>".; }
}
```

The will generate urls like `http://localhost/news/24`

Note that I removed the `/DIRECTORY/AID` from the url, as the htaccess suggest you want that to be url, as opposed to what you stated in the text.

But now the get to the `http://localhost/news/this_is_article_title` type of url. Because there is no correlation between `this_is_article_title` and the id `24`, the only way to achieve this is by either adding the id to the url too, or to have the php lookup the news-article with this title in the database.

This last solution however has some problems, as the you can't just us the title in a url. You have to escape characters. Also you'll have to add a index for the title row in the DB for better performance.

So I'll go with the first solution. We will generate urls like this

`http://localhost/news/24/this_is_article_title`

First the php part

```
function news_preview() {
$query = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5  ";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
  $url = "/news/$row[id]/".preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]/', '_', $row['title']);  
  echo "<a href=\"$url\">  ". substr($row['title'], 0,26)."...</a><br/>".; }
}
```

Next comes the htaccess part.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$ DIRECTORY/AID/news.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

That should do it I think.

Comment: +1 This approach makes much more sense to me (far better to have clean readable urls than query stringed numerics).. however I think the RegExp should be `A-Za-z0-9_-` rather than `A_Za_z0_9-_`.

Comment: @pebbl nice catch. I must have really liked my shift key, when writing the code. Eritrea; please check the edited htaccess code above.

Comment: I forgot to put `RewriteRule` before the regex. How dumb is that?

Comment: I think this may solve my problem at last. I placed the php function in my `index.php` and modified the `.htaccess` file. now when I hover over my echoed `titles` in the `index.php` page, I can see at the bottom of the browser where it is going to take me. It shows the `localhost/news/24/this_is_title` It

Answer (score 4):

The substitution (Real) URL has a number -Code- to identify the link (According to your description): ***http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/news.php?news=42***

That code is **42** in this case, but the URL you want displayed doesn't have it. Without that number, we'll get error 404 always. It's like entering only: ***http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/news.php?news=***

Have to modify the URL you want displayed by adding the code after "/", for example. Could be a hyphen, etc., but the regex has to be modified accordingly.

Here is an example entering: ***http://localhost/news/42/*** to go to ***http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/news.php?news=42***:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/?$ DIRECTORY/AID/news.php?news=$1 [NC,L]
```

That's all you need. To test this example, insert this only code in **news.php** at ***http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/***

```
<?php
if ( $_GET[ 'news' ] == '42' ) {
  echo  "HERE I AM<br /><br />";
}
?>
```

UPDATED according to OP description. Any name can be used instead of **This_is_news**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^news/([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)/?$ DIRECTORY/AID/news.php?news=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: But the example works, though. Testing with local servers  could be tricky, you may want to upload to test it. Meanhile: ¿Where are you placing the .htaccess file? ¿Are there any other .htaccess files? ¿What is exactly the localhost directory structure? ¿Is DIRECTORY a subdirectory or it is the root directory?

Comment: It seems ok, except for the include directory in the path. Best thing to do is to upload the .htaccess file along with news.php, with the code in my example, and test it.

Comment: Yes. Make sure you place .htaccess in the directory above "/DIRECTORY/" and there are not any other.htaccess files in the path.

Comment: I have uploaded the file to. www.beminet.com
The news.php and the .htaccess Check it, there is nothing

Comment: Check this link. I uploaded it to my test site and it is working: [link](http://falameda.com/news/42/). The real URL is **falameda.com/DIRECTORY/AID/news.php?news=42**

Comment: @Eritrea The URL **http://www.beminet.com/DIRECTORY/AID/** does not exist. ¿How are you testing? You have to create exactly the same directory structure for the example to work. news.php goes in AID/ directory, not in the root.

Comment: Sorry, did not Know I was supposed to do that. I uploaded it now.

Comment: Tested: *http://www.beminet.com/DIRECTORY/AID/news.php?news=42* Does not exist. Hard to understand what is Eritrea doing. One upvote for your effort @Felipe

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA Yes, I saw your link. I realize that you can access from `falameda.com/DIRECTORY/AID/news.php?news=42 ` and `http://falameda.com/news/42/` but, What I needed is not the `news/42/` because 42 is the row number for the news. I need the title after the `news/` like `news/This_is_news` 

Thanks anyway, this is the biggest hope so far i've gotten

Comment: Perfect. It did not when I tested.

Comment: It did not work. I am putting this question for a bounty of 150 tomorrow, before I loose my mind. Stick around.

Comment: Hope you will get the correct answer, whichever it is. Good luck, anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I have placed a bounty for it. Please check it and let me know if you can.

Comment: This question is more thoroughly explained now, with +100 bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Place RewriteBase right after RewriteEngine On
It will set up rewrite engine correctly before you start redirecting

Comment: Well, I added your suggetion, but I am getting Internal server Error

Comment: Can I see how it looks now, please?

Comment: 42 and 46 are the same, I have news by id from 1-100

Comment: I wanted to see how .htaccess looks. Sorry for confusing you

Comment: No problem`
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ news.php?news=$1 [QSA,L]
`

Comment: Please, note what RewriteBase requires the parameter (your base path). It should look  `RewriteBase /DIRECTORY/AID/` Just add the correct path

Comment: Can you please, add .htaccess screenshot again?

Comment: Here it is: thanks for keeping up. This has been a read headache http://imm.io/N1j8

Comment: Must work correctly as far as you have folder /DIRECTORY/AID/ in your web root folder. Do you still have error 500?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I'm unable to answer your question in PHP or Apache (although I am using a hand-rolled REST converter to create URL addresses on my current project), but from what I understand, you want your user to type out **http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/article.php?a_id=24** and the address bar should end up like **http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/news/this_is_article_title**.

I'm not entirely sure what benefits this provides for you, and please bear in mind my solution will NOT allow your end-user to type the RESTful URL and end up at the page with the QueryString address. You'd need some extra legwork to do this, and even more legwork to keep it in sync with the DB (I'd recommend a script that deseminates the RESTFUL URL, queries the DB for the topic then returns the ID or page content ... but that's an different Stack Overflow question for another day.

**SOLUTION**
My proposed solution requires HTML5 doctype and a *very light* sprinkling of Javascript.

```
history.replaceState(null, "history title here", "news/this_is_article_title");
```

What this does is it changes the URL in the address bar without triggering a page redirect, reload or anything else. This javascript can be dynamically written with your PHP so as the page is served, the address is updated. The higher up in the document it is, the faster the change.

Here's a jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/uT3RP/1/

Unfortunately they run the code in an iframe so it doesn't control the main address bar, so I included an alert displaying what the address bar location would say, for proof. It's not the most elegant of solutions. I wouldn't even recommend doing what you're doing without the failsafes of making sure the URL displayed can be used to get to the same page. Disclaimer aside ... your problem is solved with 1 line of js and a doctype change (if you aren't using HTML5).

You can stop flogging poor ol' htaccess and get on with your project :)

Answer (score 1):

**This is a problem about URL-Rewrite and String-to-Id Algorithm.**

Above all, please remember that what ever your url changes by rewrite module, the url  in the browser bar  always contains the post param like id or string(about your news).

Now to the question. Our purpose is just to rewrite the Url:

```
http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/news/this_is_article_title
```

to:

```
http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/news.php?a_id=24
```

With the rewrite module, we can only rewrite it to:

```
http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/news.php?title=this_is_article_title
```

and here is the htaccess part, alrealdy tested on a [htaccess-online-tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

```
RewriteRule ^DIRECTORY/AID/news/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ DIRECTORY/AID/news.php?title=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The remaining work is build a algorithm for mapping the title to the news which rewrite module cannot help us(especially you manually rewrite the url one by one). We can use php code below:

```
<?php

//write url reflect to news title.
function build_news_url_by_title(){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<a href=\"news/".strtr(substr($row['title'], 0,26), " ", "_")."\">".substr($row['title'], 0,26)."</a>";
    }   
}

function get_news_by_title($title){
    $real_title = strtr($title, "_", " ");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE title LIKE %".$real_title."% LIMIT 1";
    return mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}

$title = $_POST['title'];

$news = get_news_by_title($title);

//some code return the news
...
```

So the url:

```
http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/news/this_is_article_title
```

can give us the news also.

**Finally, from the steps above, if we type url**

```
http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/news/this_is_article_title
```

**in the browser bar, it can be also give us the news. And it has none bussiness about the stupid ID. And Though, there maybe some bugs with the code above, do not put it on your product server.**

Answer (score 1):

Can you see if this works?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /DIRECTORY/AID/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
^news/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)$ news.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

**EDIT :** Fixed the regex character class definitions.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the title of the URL. If you wish to show that in URL, then you must include it in the link as well, like this:

```
<a href="news.php?news_id=$id&title=$url_tile">
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a complicated problem because you do not know where it really is doing wrong.

I would suggest you divide what you want to do into small parts and make each of them work properly before you join them together. For example:

```
 1. Make sure .htaccess file is readable and can do some simple thing, preventing directory indexing for instance.
 2. Make sure you can redirect something with simple html code.
 3. Make sure you can run Felipe's example code successfully. From here you can get good picture of what is going on.
```

And as a side note:

It is more common to rewrite like this:

```
http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/news.php?a_id=24 TO -->
http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/news/24_this_is_article_title
```

Notice the id 24 is still carried over to the rewritten url. That will make pattern matching simpler and avoid unnecessary processing of title duplication.

Answer (score 1):

Change the link:

```
echo "<a href=\"news.php?news=$row[id]\"> ". substr($row['title'], 0,26)."</a>
```

to

```
echo "<a href=\"news/$row['title']\">".$row['title']."</a>"
```

That way, the link will go to `news/$row['title']` instead of `news.php?id=...`. And now in the page `DIRECOTORY/AID/news.php`, you should get the `id` and check if it is a number **OR** text, and in case of text match it up with the `$row['title']` and then load the page accordingly.

Notes:

1. This assumes that $row['title'] is unique across all other rows.
2. The title does not contain non HTML content, in which case you will have to URL Escape those characters.

If the title is not going to be unique then you should probably do `news/{id}/{title}` and then in rewrite it to `DIRECTORY/AID/news.php?id={id}&title={title}` and then you can base it off of the ID instead of the title.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Change it to `"<a href=\"news/$row[title]\">"` and see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you feel your `.htaccess` file is not working as intended then this is a server configuration issue and most likely to do with the `AllowOverride` directive under the Apache configuration.

In your `http.conf` file find the section which looks something as follows:

```
<Directory>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Change the `AllowOverride` directive to allow `All`.

```
<Directory>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

The next thing is to ensure that the `mod_rewrite` module is enabled for your XAMPP install. Search for the following line:

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Remove the `#` so it looks like so:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

**Restart the Apache service** after saving all your changes.

Also ensure you are using the `RewriteBase` directive in your `.htaccess` configuration as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /DIRECTORY/AID/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
^news/([A-Za-z0-9_]+)(/)?$ news.php?title=$1 [QSA,L]
```

The next thing is to ensure your links are pointing to the Rewrite URL. Your echo line should be something like the following:

```
echo "<a href=\"news/" . $row['title'] . "\">  " . substr($row['title'], 0, 26) . "...</a><br />";
```

Now since you can only retrieve titles with this URL rewrite method we need to configure your PHP script accordingly to retrieve the content based on the title. If you still want to use "id" only for retrieving the record then your Rewrite URL should contain the "id" in it in some form. Typical examples of this form are:

- `news/the_news_title_123`
- `news/123_the_news_title`
- `news/123/the_news_title`

Answer (score 0):

**I cannot comment so I have to answer.**

Reading all answers and your question, it is not clear what you want. At least for me. You say, for example:

`http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/article.php?a_id=24` to

`http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/article/this_is_article_title`

But I guess that's not quite right, unless you want

`http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/article.php?a_id=24`

to be the URL entered in the browser address bar and if so, what would be the purpose of the redirection? Finally, any visitor would have to type precisely what you don't want them to type.

My guess is that you want the friendly URL to be entered:

`http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/article/this_is_article_title` , so the question should be the other way around:

`http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/article/this_is_article_title` TO

`http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/article.php?a_id=24`

The next thing that does not seem to be clear, is what's displayed in the browser bar? The only answer is: The entered URL. No way it can show anything different.

In short: If you want **http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/article/this_is_article_title** to show in the addres bar, that's what you have to enter.  The real URL, the SUBSTITUTION  (**http://localhost/DIRECTORY/AID/article.php?a_id=24**), is never shown and is never typed. That's what redirection is for.

On the other hand, it is not clear either how the ID numbers provided by news.php are expected to be converted to strings like **article/this_is_article_title**. ¿Where are those strings, how many ID numbers are, what kind of algorithm or formula should be used to achieve that conversion, which of those IDs are 'root" as you mentioned in a comment and how can they be identified, etc.? You should elaborate more on this point because it seems improvised and incoherent with your previous comments.

I might be wrong, of course. I am just guessing to try to help with your question.

Please, geniuses, don't downvote this answer, read it. I am not trying to answer the question and I am really far from being a genius.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you buddy. You comment is more confusing that the problem. I though I made it very clear, please see the question again. It is self explanatory, and I will update it to make it even more thorough.

Comment: Ok, I have corrected some mistakes I had made on the way. Please check it now

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you've forgotten the slash in front of “news.php”.